# Can a fire user beat an electricity user?

Tags: super-powers

I want to know how someone who has fire powers could fight someone with electricity powers.  The electricity user would also be also immune to heat and light so is there some way my pyrokinetic could beat or at least damage them?

Comment: While I think there is a valid question there and you could probably get it accepted with the proper corrections, I'll refrain from answering and am VTC-ing until the question fit the stack policy. As is, it's 1) opinion-based and 2) need clarity. You could improve the question by further specifying the powers at play and rephrasing to make it more factual (ex: How can a fire user beat someone immune to heat and light?).

Comment: Do Faraday Cages exist? (Or other object that grants "immunity to lightning")

Comment: "Immune to heat" is a heck of a thing.  Completely immune?  Their flesh won't burn if immersed in magma?  You could drop them into the sun?

Comment: Sort to ground with water,

Comment: You don't appear to be building a world. It appears you're asking random superpower questions. This site is about helping you develop consistent characteristics and rules for your world, wherein an infinite number of stories might be told. That's important, because as written, the only valid answer to your question is "sure, if you want him/her to."

Answer (score 2):

## Suffocation

Now, this is highly dependent on how your pyrokinetic's powers work, but assuming that fuel is still being oxidized for combustion, have your pyrokinetic start a fire inside the Electro-wannabe's lungs.  It won't matter that their lungs won't burn if there's nothing in there to metabolise.

Comment: What I was thinking about. Alternatively, I you can't start a fire *in* their lungs, immersing them in fire long enough will deprive them of oxygen just as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Molten pool of glassy lava created from the soil under the feet of the opponent. Bonus point if you can cool that one fast enough to trap your opponent's feet into it.
2. Heating the water/gasses behind at a [projectile in a barrel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam_cannon) pointed to the opponent.
3. Sudden heat on the key structural elements of the building the opponent is under ([concrete spalling in action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CixMjo5VtgA) - bonus point, [the shrapnel can help](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbFzMnSBp1o).
4. Fill the opponent's lungs with NOx resulted by overheating the air surrounding him.
5. kill him with a blast of gamma ray or neutrons resulted from the thermal body radiation of some air heated at hundred millions of Kelvins. Or from the fusion explosion you so generate.